# How to add a where clause to Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I have been trying to figure out how to add a `Where` clause to this. I need

```
Where OrderHeader.OrderStatus = "NEW"
```

Any help is a appreciated.

```
using (context)
{
    var orderData = context.OrderHeaders
                           .Join(context.OrderLines,
                                 OrderHeader => OrderHeader.Id,
                                 OrderLine => OrderLine.OrderHeaderId,
                                 (OrderHeader, OrderLine) => new
                                               {
                                                   Id = OrderHeader.Id
                                               }).ToList()

    foreach (var order in orderData)
    {
        CreateOrder(order.Id, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: That query is going to return duplicate OrderHeader ids assuming that they can have more than one OrderLine.

Comment: @juharr True I don't think I need that join for this part of my code. Is there a way to add Distinct?

Comment: Yeah, you'd just do `.Distinct()` before the `ToList()`.  I assume the join was to only get OrderHeader ids that have at least one OrderLine.  If so you could do `.Where(oh => oh.OrderLines.Any())` instead without creating duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
context.OrderHeaders
    .Where(o => o.OrderStatus == "NEW")
    .Join(...
```

Comment: Thank you. That was way to easy.